# Error query failed , check manual line 3

Tags: php, sql, download, upload

My upload.php and view.php are working fine but I am not able to create a download links to download files. db name = dbtuts.

and the link for download option is:

```
<td><a href='download.php?id=<?php echo $row['file_name']; ?>'>Download</a></td>
```

Here is the code for download.php

```
<?php
  // Make sure an ID was passed
    if(isset($_GET['id'])) {
        // Get the ID$id
        $file_name= ($_GET['id']);
        // Make sure the ID is in fact a valid ID
    if($file_name == NULL) {
        die('The name is invalid!');
    }
    else {`enter code here`
        // Connect to the database
        $dbLink = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', "", 'dbtuts');
        if(mysqli_connect_errno()) {
            die("MySQL connection failed: ".mysqli_connect_error());
        }

         // Fetch the file information
        $query = "
            SELECT file, type, size
            FROM tbl_uploads
            WHERE `file` = {$file_name}";
        $result = $dbLink->query($query);

        if($result) {
            // Make sure the result is valid
            if($result->num_rows == 1) {
            // Get the row
                $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

                header("Content-Type: ".$row['type']);
                header("Content-Length: ".$row['size']);
                header("Content-Disposition: attachment"); 
                // disopsition = attachment to force download request
                // Print data
                echo $row['data'];
            }
            else {
                echo 'Error! No file exists with that ID.';
            }
            // Free the mysqli resources
            @mysqli_free_result($result);
        }
        else {
            // if there is an error excuting the query
            echo "Error! Query failed: <pre>{$dbLink->error}</pre>";
        }
        // close database connection
        @mysqli_close($dbLink);
    }
}
else {
    // if no ID passed
    echo 'Error! No ID was passed.';
}
?>
```

Comment: `WHERE \`file\` = {$file_name}` I assume `$file_name` is a string? If so it needs to be enclosed in `'` marks... though why aren't you using bound parameters?

Comment: Filename is a string and must be in single quotes. Learn about prepared statements to prevent SQL injection

Comment: Your code uses `@` to suppress warnings/errors. That is bad practice. Remove those and handle all errors you can and let other errors to be handled by an error handler. Suppressing them will make debugging a lot harder.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.